# Getting user details by any request to spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I would like to get after correctly logging in to the system, so that the service /user always returns a response in the form of a login to which the user is logged in.

But I have a problem because the service returns status 404.

spring controller:

```
@RestController
public class UserController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/user", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public UserView home(@CurrentUser User principal) {
        return principal != null ? new UserView(principal) : null;
    }
}
```

own annotation:

```
@Target({ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@AuthenticationPrincipal
public @interface CurrentUser {
}
```

service:

```
@Service("userDetailsService")
public class MyUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {
private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

@Autowired
DataSource dataSource;

@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String userName) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplateObject = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    String SQL = "select username, enabled from admin.ebpp_user where username = ?";
    User user = (User)jdbcTemplateObject.queryForObject(SQL, new Object[]{userName}, new JdbcUserMapper());
    logger.info("User: "+ user);
    return user;
}
}
```

mapper:

```
public class JdbcUserMapper implements RowMapper {
    @Override
    public Object mapRow(ResultSet resultSet, int rowNum) throws SQLException {

        return User.Builder.anUser()
                .withUsername(resultSet.getString("username"))
                .build();
    }
}
```

and finally main configure class:

```
  @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        auth.jdbcAuthentication()
                .dataSource(dataSource)
                .usersByUsernameQuery("select username, password, enabled from admin.ebpp_user where username=?")
                .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select username, authority from admin.authorities where username = ?");
    }
```

log with userDetailsService looks :

```
2018-02-19 22:58:42,714 INFO[com.MyUserDetailsService] user: User{username='test'}
```

When it calls: localhost:8080/rest/home then receives "404 Not Found"
Does anyone have an idea why I can not download the user through the service?

edit.1.

my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation=" http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         version="3.0">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/context/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
</web-app>
```

and applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd">
    <bean id="userDetailsService"
                class="com.MyUserDetailsService" />

    <jee:jndi-lookup id="dbDataSource"
                     jndi-name="java:/TestDS"
                     expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource" />

</beans>
```

edit.2

When i added code:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/user", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public UserView home(@CurrentUser User principal) {
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        UserDetails userDetail = (UserDetails) auth.getPrincipal();
        // userDetail contains data

    }
```

then userDetail contains data (in debugger mode), but "@CurrentUser User principal" jest still null

Comment: Do you have errors on the server?

Comment: zero errors on the server

Comment: Do you have a controller, which is mapped to the path /rest/home?

Comment: Can you post your web
XML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to receive the Principal you have define it as Method argument and then load the User by the name containing in the principal.

```
@RestController
public class UserController {

  @Autowired
  MyUserDetailsService userdetailservice;

  @RequestMapping(value = "/user", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public UserView home(Principal principal) {
      User user = userdetailservice.loadUserByUsername(principal.getName());
      return principal != null ? new UserView(user) : null;
  }
}
```